# Umbraco 4.10.1 Navigation

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I'm trying to create a top navigation in Umbraco 4.10.1 that is based upon the children of my home page.

Initially I had tried the following, but kept getting "Error loading Razor Script" in place of my navigation:

```
<umbraco:Macro  runat="server" language="cshtml">
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.AncestorOrSelf(1048).Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <li><a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
</umbraco:Macro>
```

When I run in Debug Mode through VS 2012, it breaks on the @foreach line. When I inspect Model, it does not include AncestorOrSelf. Am I missing a using?

Once I couldn't get that working, I included the pre-written Navigation macro, but it also shows the "Error loading Razor Script".

Comment: I take you have set the rendering engine to "Mvc" in umbracosettings.config?

Comment: Nope, haven't touched umbracosettings.config. Opened it and it shows: <templates><useAspNetMasterPages>true</useAspNetMasterPages><defaultRenderingEngine>WebForms</defaultRenderingEngine></templates>

Comment: I think it may have had something with me updating the Razor and WebPages to version 2.0 via NuGet. Started over with a clean install and all is well.

Comment: If you are using visual Studio I recommend using nuget package installer as follows: (1) Create Empty ASP.NET Website project. (2) On nuget Console Type "Install-Package umbracocms". after this usual umbraco database setup and change template to Razor in config file bit. Hope this helps (it helped me). Good luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to stem from upgrading Razor to V2. With a clean install and the original version of Razor that is included in the NuGet package, the navigation code posted above works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Aah in which case do the following in umbracosettings.config

```
<defaultRenderingEng‌​ine>Mvc</defaultRenderingEngine>
```

And then do iisreset.

Comment: This is one thing that has always annoyed me when I come back to trying Umbraco...there is no central documentation on the system. It is scattered throughout blog posts, forums, some user contributed PDFs, and their Umbraco.tv product (which I don't even think is up to date).

Is there a comprehensive resource that has all the documentation I need to get up and running for the latest 4.10.1 version? Or is flying to Europe for training the only way to get everything in one place?

Comment: In general it is somewhat true. But if you look at the release document for the 4.10.x release then there is a guide about things to do when upgrade it to 4.10.x. Does not much help as it should in the Documentation.

Comment: Don't think you need to do in person training to learn umbraco unless you have loads of umbraco projects in hand. I like the framework as its flexible (and lot more) and as a dev I try to find my way through blogs and forums etc. I know the frustration and prob as lots of other umbraco devs all round the world has/had felt the same but I can tell you that over the years both framework and the documentation has got lot better. I think the best thing to do is to help each other out via forums and blogs. All the best.

Comment: Peryash, it seemed to be failing because I updated the Razor engine via Nuget. As I mentioned above, a clean install without updating to Razor V2 and the navigation worked.